# $x^k = na$ has solution over the field $F, \text{char} F \neq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I came up with an interesting **Hypothesis**.

> Suppose we are in the field $F, \text{char }F \neq 2$. Let's fix an arbitrary element $a \in F$. Is it true that at least one equation $x^k=n\cdot a$, ($k\in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{1\}, n \neq 0$ in $F$) has roots in $F$?

**Examples**.

1. $F = \mathbb{C}-$ obvious.
2. $F=\mathbb{Z}_p$. Since every nonzero element $a$ has inverse $a^{-1}$ then $x^2 = aa^{-1} = 1$ has roots.
3. $F = \mathbb{R}$. Either $x^2 = a$ or $x^2 = -a$ has roots.
4. $F = \mathbb{Q}$. $a = \frac{p}{q}$. Then $x^2 = a \cdot (pq) = p^2$ has roots.
5. $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. $a = \sqrt{2}$. Then $x^3 = 2\sqrt{2}$ has roots.

**Counterexamples**.

1. $F = \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. $a = \pi$. Since $\pi$ is not an algebraic number then the equation $x^k = n\pi$ has no solutions.

**But** Can it be generalized somehow?

Comment: Try $F = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, $a = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Okay, I can generalize my hypothesis to solve this example =).

Comment: Alright... then how about $F=\Bbb Q(\pi), a=\pi$?

Comment: Probably it is not generalizable =(. Should I delete my question?

Comment: No, it is a good question.  If Mike doesn't want to post an answer himself, perhaps you should answer your own question for the benefit of future visitors to this site.

Comment: I agree with @Omnomnomnom, this is a good question! If nobody else writes up an answer, I'll do so sometime tomorrow.